# How do I deal with a pointer when Swift calls C API

Tags: c, swift, pointers, language-interoperability

The c Lib API :  mycapi.h

```
typedef struct{
    int  itype;
    double * dx;
    double * dy;
}MyObjInfo;

typedef MyObjInfo * MyObjHandle；

MyObjHandle MyObjInit(const char *pFile);
```

add myapi.h as module

my swift code :

```
import Foundation
import mycapiModule


var h:MyObjHandle = MyObjInit("/home/a")
var o:MyObjInfo = h.memory
////to do somethings
//...
h.destroy()
h = nil
print("\(o.itype)")
```

**So my questions are:**

1. Why am I still able to use `o`  after `h.destroy()`?
2. Do I have to destroy `h` and `o`?

Comment: I think you need to utilize UnsafeMutablePointer<Type> : You can read a about working with C here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not access directly.

**To access C / Cpp Library, In Swift programming language with XCode use below way.**

add main.mm file with

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ProjectName-swift.h"
//#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

 @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment - @UIApplicationMain in AppDelegate

Now by using bridge you can access C / Cpp library or directly from Swift programming language.